# how to use export-state then add the custom aura and grandpa authorities

Tags: genesis

I've been trying to use the `export-state` and then add the custom set of authorities to the `aura` and `grandpa` as per the [`Simulate network tutorial`](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/#create-a-custom-chain-specification), but i'm always getting the file as a raw genesis file and no way to add the authorities.

The tutorial says to create a custom spec then, change the values and then generate the raw spec. That works, but i don't get the data, which is important to have.

I've also read multiple times this post, which clarified few things but not my use-case [How to configure a Substrate Network with Injected Block History from a snapshot or database backup?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-to-configure-a-substrate-network-with-injected-block-history-from-a-snapshot)

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the tutorial link?

Comment: updated the message with the link, for convenience case I'm pasting it here https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/#create-a-custom-chain-specification