# Export state of a running chain and run it as alice

Tags: runtime-upgrade, migration, database, on-runtime-upgrade, state

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to spin up a test chain(with imported real chain data) with alice(so I can start it from genesis and start producing blocks with --alice flag) and after dumping the state of the current chain:

```shell
$ ./target/release/edgeware export-state --base-path /tmp/edgewaretest/ --chain edgeware > edg_export.json
```

I then change the sudo key to Alice and validator key to Alice. Based on these scripts:
https://github.com/Phala-Network/phala-blockchain/blob/master/scripts/js/src/bin/chainSpecUtils.js#L92
https://github.com/zeitgeistpm/zeitgeist/blob/a9ff9693dbfeb9527ee3b3ddb5a9873940fedc1f/scripts/runtime-upgrade/test_runtime_upgrade.sh#L30

Plus I removed the bootnodes but the chain will still not produce blocks:

```
# ./target/release/edgeware --chain=edg_state.json  --base-path=/tmp/edg_exported_state --alice --validator   
2022-08-21 20:29:11 Edgeware Node
2022-08-21 20:29:17  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x2192…24e0), finalized #0 (0
x2192…24e0), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s
2022-08-21 20:29:22  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x2192…24e0), finalized #0 (0
x2192…24e0), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0
2022-08-21 20:29:27  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x2192…24e0), finalized #0 (0
x2192…24e0), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0
```

I based this solution on the 3rd solution that was given here:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/439/560

Chain used:
https://github.com/edgeware-network/edgeware-node/tree/erup-5-latest

What am I doing wrong? And what is the correct way to change validator and sudo key to alice?

Thanks!

Comment: hey, I can't see a link to edg_state.json. 

Is Alice the only registered validator in the chain spec? If not then you need Alice and Bob, etc, before the chain starts producing blocks. It also makes a difference if the chain is Live or Development. I'd bet its not Development, and its waiting for the validators in edg_state before it starts making blocks.

Comment: Can you try again with additionally `--force-authoring` and if that does not work also `--tmp`?

Comment: Is there a simpler way or a better tool to use to replace/change the sudo key?

Answer (score 0):

Is that a standalone chain?

If yes, then I suggest you follow this [example](https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/state.html#fork-off).