Loading rocks db snapshots details
Goal:
If I have a folder containing rocksdb snapshots, and I just want to load the database dump such that it can read the various pallet's state and constants.
For the context I do not need the node to be connected or connect to other peers. I just need the data to be available via rpc, not even extrinsic functionality is required the goal is just load the rocks db data.
Questions:

is the command substrate-node --base-path=<base-path> as configured in https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1019/5261 enough for this?
in this case is it possible to use even a fresh clone of substrate-node-template for this, independently of the data stored? I am saying this because the compiled wasm and metadata should be loaded from rocks db. Again for my purpose consensus and transaction logic is not relevant
Is there maybe any other way that I am missing to reconstruct the state from the rocks db snapshot?

Thanks in advance
